# Sign convention of characteristic nu in elliptic integral of the 3rd kind C++1z implementation

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++17, cmath

## TL;DR

Boost.Math and gcc's implementation of math special function `ellint_3()`
give different results. Both can't be right, right?
Coming C++ standard implementations should get it right, preferably on the 1st try.

My question is: how?

### Someone is wrong on the internet (or something in Denmark, if you prefer Shakespeare)

The special functions `std::ellint_3(k,nu,phi)`, `std::comp_ellint_3(k,nu)`
in gcc's implementation 
([live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hHkO3aTeYJFiyjUL)):

```
const auto pi = std::acos(-1.0);
const auto k  = 0.0;

std::cout << "nu\tincomp.\tcompl.\texpect\n";
for (auto nu : {-0.9, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.9})
{
    auto expected = pi/(2*std::sqrt(1-nu));
    std::cout 
        << nu << '\t' 
        << std::ellint_3(k, nu, pi/2) << '\t'
        << std::comp_ellint_3(k, nu) << '\t'
        << expected << '\n';                
}
```

and their `std::tr1` equivalents 
([live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HWlupkDweqEwAOhp)) 
give incorrect results for non-zero values of parameter `nu`:

```
nu      incomp. compl.  expect
-0.9    4.96729 4.96729 1.13958
-0.5    2.22144 2.22144 1.28255
0       1.5708  1.5708  1.5708
0.5     1.28255 1.28255 2.22144
0.9     1.13958 1.13958 4.96729
```

The results in 
[Boost.Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/ellint/ellint_3.html) 
`boost::math::ellint_3()` 
in gcc and clang seem to be correct 
([live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9PbyZcC7cicsE2Y4):)

```
nu      incomp. expect
-0.9    1.13958 1.13958
-0.5    1.28255 1.28255
0       1.5708  1.5708
0.5     2.22144 2.22144
0.9     4.96729 4.96729
```

### Background

Documentation in TR1, Boost library, ISO 29124, C++17 Draft, 
[en.cppreference.org](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_math/ellint_3) 
and documentation comments of gcc's implementation of `ellint_3(k,nu,phi)` and`comp_ellint_3(k,nu)`
consistently refer to the definition of the 
[elliptic integral of the 3rd kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_third_kind) 
(parameter order/convention adapted here for convenience)

[image: elliptic integral 3rd kind, minus sign]

given in Lagrange form by
Abramowitz, Milton & Stegun, Irene: Handbook of mathematical functions. (1964).

For `k=0` and `phi=pi/2` the integral simpifies to `pi/(2*sqrt(1-nu))`:

[image: elliptic integral 3rd kind, special case]

according to 
(Bronstein, §1.1.3, no. 311, 312, german 24th edn, Leipzig 1989) 
and 
[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ellipticPi%5Bnu,+pi%2F2,0%5D).

However, there exists another definition with opposite sign (order of parameters changed for consistency here)

[image: elliptic integral 3rd kind, plus sign]

referred to in 
[Carlsson](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9409227),
[Press, W. et al.: Numerical Recipes in C, eq. 6.11.21, p.261](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c6-11.pdf).

These "plus sign sources" also give hints, 
how to implement these functions using Carlson's integrals R_F and R_J.

So, some libraries chose the "plus sign" for implementation, while others took the extra effort to adopt the "minus sign", according to [root.cern.ch](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/group__SpecFunc.html#ga53f1b9e37d4e4dfe31496721869e6656):

- plus sign : [GNU Scientific Library (GSL)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Definition-of-Legendre-Forms.html#Definition-of-Legendre-Forms), Planet Math, CERNLIB
- minus sign : Abramowitz/Stegun, Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha, Boost.Math, [C++ TR1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1687.pdf), ISO/IEC 29124:2010, and coming C++1z standard

[Gcc bug report 66689](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66689)
and [testcases](https://github.com/emsr/tr29124_test/blob/master/diff_special_function.cpp)
seem to indicate, that gcc took the (wrong?) decision to orient on GSL.

### Conclusion / Question

Is there a (constructive) way out of this mess and to choose the "right side of force"?
At first glance, this seems to be an opinion-based question, 
but there should be no opinion-based answer about truth or, 
at least, correct documentation.

BTW, apologize for the inconvience, and thanks for all the `<*)))<`.

Comment: Sounds like a straightforward gcc bug, no?

Comment: What's the question really? You already pointed to the gcc bug.

Comment: This will be fixed soon in gcc8.  Still discussing whether to backport in the middle of version 7.  I obviously got confused between the conventions.  We will document what happened.  Sigh.